Getting file path, line and column number for pydocstring in Helix Editor
I'm trying to use commands to execute python module pydocstring to generate docstrings in the Helix editor.
My Helix config.toml:
[keys.normal]  
C-g = ":insert-output pydocstring -f numpy <file path> <line_number>, <column_number>"

But I have difficulty getting the file path and line number and column number to generate the docstring I want. How can I do this correctly?
My goal is to get a solution like this:
def new_func(self, n1:int, n2:int) -> None:
    """ Autogenerated docstring here!

        Parameters
        ----------
        self : TYPE
        n1 : int   
        Parameters
        ----------
        self : TYPE
        n1 : int
        n2 : int
    
        Returns
        -------
        None
    """


A solution was found that partially satisfied me.

pipx install pydocstring
Put script to the dir: ~/.config/helix/my_scripts/pydocstring_gen.py

#!/home/my_username/.local/pipx/venvs/pydocstring/bin/python

import sys
import pydocstring


def generate_docstring(source, position, formatter='google'):
    """ Docstring gen func.
        Availible formatter types:
          'google'
          'numpy'
          'reST'
    """
    docstring = pydocstring.generate_docstring(source, position, formatter)
    if docstring:
        return f'"""{docstring}"""'
    else:
        return "No docstring generated"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    source = sys.argv[1]
    # print(f"raw source str: {source}")
    
    source = f" \n{(source or '').lstrip()}\n    pass"
    # print(f"formatted source: {source}")

    # hardcore it!
    position = (2, 2)

    formatter = sys.argv[2]
    # print(f"formatter: {formatter}")
    
    docstring = generate_docstring(source, position, formatter)
    print(docstring)


Edit ~/.config/helix/config.toml

[keys.normal]
C-A-j = ["yank_main_selection_to_clipboard", "collapse_selection", "move_line_down", ':insert-output ~/.config/helix/my_scripts/pydocstring_gen.py "$(xclip -o -selection clipboard)" "google"']
C-A-k = ["yank_main_selection_to_clipboard", "collapse_selection", "move_line_down", ':insert-output ~/.config/helix/my_scripts/pydocstring_gen.py "$(xclip -o -selection clipboard)" "numpy"']
C-A-l = ["yank_main_selection_to_clipboard", "collapse_selection", "move_line_down", ':insert-output ~/.config/helix/my_scripts/pydocstring_gen.py "$(xclip -o -selection clipboard)" "reST"']

Let stand on the python method def line, press the 'x' key, press clt+alt+j (or bind another keys), and the docstring will be added on subsequent lines after the selection line.

I used a simple rule in the script: create documentation on one line of a method definition, without scanning the body of the entire method. However, this may not be enough.
